# Add indents to bullet points

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I am looking at getting an effect like:

[image]

But my current effect is:

[image]

What do I need to add to my css to get the indent to work like the effect I want, so the second line of any bullet point is indented? currently the HTML setup is just `<ul><li></li><ul>` with the CSS being:

```
li {
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

And also incorporating Bootstrap via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

All of this bullet list is overall within a `<section>` with styling:

```
section {
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code in snippet?

Comment: do you need for any reason list-style-position: inside; ? This caused the issue imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you get the desired effect your use of `list-style-position: inside;` is messing it up for you.

```html
<ul>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio delectus magnam nobis, nulla dolore accusamus.</li>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio delectus magnam nobis, nulla dolore accusamus.</li>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio delectus magnam nobis, nulla dolore accusamus.</li>
 <ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I change the indent of the bullets so they are further right?

Comment: To further indent the bullet points you need to add padding to the left: `ul li {padding-left:10px;}`